# Artaxerxes the great and just king

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

What is the correct tag for a puzzle on Puzzling Stack Exchange that is centered around the following paragraph?

> And I, even I, Artaxerxes, the great and just king, do make a decree to all the treasurers which are beyond the river, that whatsoever Ezra the priest, the scribe of the law of the God of heaven, shall require of you, it be done speedily.

Comment: When you see the answer, you immediately know that it is correct.

Comment: Well its got every letter of the alphabet in there for a start...

Comment: What tags are appropriate depends on what the puzzle actually *is*. A tag which gives the game away is not appropriate.

Comment: No right answers yet, or…?

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it :)

Answer (score 4):

maybe

> it is [enigmatic-puzzle](/questions/tagged/enigmatic-puzzle)?

Answer (score 2):

Since you ask specifically for the correct *tag*, I'm going to say

> [pangram](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pangram), since the sentence contains every letter of the alphabet at least once.

It could also be

> [knowledge](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/knowledge) or [literature](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/literature),

because the quoted sentence is

> an extract from the King James Bible, specifically [Ezra 7:21](http://biblehub.com/kjv/ezra/7-21.htm), except with the words "great and just" added (to make it a proper pangram, since it didn't contain the letter J before).